# 3D cubes in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, 3d, cubes

This is my code in malab:

```
clear all
close all
colores = ['b','y','g','y','r','c','k'];

nCubos=6;
cubos=cell(1,nCubos);
cubos{1}(60:140, 70:150, 70:150) =0.6;
cubos{2}(107:177, 151:221, 90:160) =0.6;
cubos{3}(80:150, 160:230, 161:231) =0.6;
cubos{4}(153:183, 193:223, 161:181) =0.6;
cubos{5}(57:97, 160:200, 120:160) =0.6;
cubos{6}(130:180, 132:182, 161:211) =0.6;

cubos{3}=imrotate(cubos{3},40,'crop');

for p=1:nCubos
    color = colores(mod(p,length(colores))+1);
    disp(color)
    [x,y,z] = ind2sub(size(cubos{p}), find(cubos{p}));
    plot3(x,y,z,'color',color,'marker','.')
    pause(0.01)
    hold on;
    axis([0 256 0 256 0 256]);
end
hold off;
```

and this is the output:

[image]

I would like to create randoms cubes like this every time I execute the program, with differents sizes and positions without overlapping, but with intersect in one face or vertice.

Thanks!!

Comment: creating random numbers to give to cubes is easy (`rand` or `randi`), create random numbers so that cubes dont' intersect is very hard.

Comment: yes, i know how to create random numbers to increase or decrease number cubes, but i dont know how i give random positions to cubes without overlapping each other

Comment: Thats hard, because once you are giving the number a constraint, then it suddenly its not random. If you do not care about having a real random distribution, the best way is probably first generating random positions, then random sizes that make sure do not collide with those random positions or existing cubes, iteratively. You need to write a cube-cube collision code for that.